# Add button for new page created by Link in Vaadin application

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

I have Vaadin app that provides some calculations. 
As a result of these calculations, the application redirects me to the file system through Link-mechanism, so that I have new page with many new Links.

So the question is how to add to this page one button?

Initial link looks like:

```
public static Link linkToNewTab(String caption, String url) {
    Link lnk = link(caption, url);
    lnk.setTargetName("_blank");
    return lnk;
}
```

Comment: What vaadin version are you using?

Comment: You want to link to the result page or you want to add this button _on_ the result page?

Comment: André Schild, I use Vaadin 8

Comment: cfrick, I want button on the result page